# Big O of this function

Tags: algorithm

I've been working through my textbook and learning the basics of Big O notation, but am a bit confused if whether or not my answer is right, since I don't have a solution manual.

> Give the big O for the following functions by determining the dominant
>   term.
>
> ```
> b. T(n) = 2n^3 / n + n^2 - 3n*n + 12
> ```

**My Attempt**

At first I thought by simply simplifying and getting 12, this would simply be `O(1)`, since it is a constant value.

However I was wondering since the problem had a `(tricky)` on the side whether this was too good to be true.

Another thing I have been thinking about, is that since `n^3` grows much larger than any of the other terms before simplification, it could also be `O(n^3)`.

I've solved some problems like this using the "Definition of Big O notation" , but am wondering if I am missing anything here. Some hints would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: are there any parentheses in the question? for example is the expression supposed to be interpreted as: `(2n^3 / n) + n^2 - 3n*n + 12` or `2n^3 / (n + n^2 - 3n*n + 12)` I'm assuming you're meaning `(2n^3 / n) + n^2 - 3n*n + 12` if you're getting 12 as answer

Comment: As a matter of fact `T(n) = 12` irrespective of how complex the original expression can be. Therefore it is `O(1)`.

Comment: Yes it is `(2n^3 / n) + n^2 - 3n*n + 12`, Alright , I thought it was `O(1)` Thanks!